# sum of 2 number with object and method

Tags: php, object, methods

why am I getting these errors?
Undefined variable: num1
Cannot access empty property

```
class sum{
    public $num1=1;
public function fun($num2){
     return $this->$num1+$num2;
    }
}
$number = new sum();
echo $number->fun(3);
```

Comment: `$this->$num1` <- remove the second dollar sign.

Answer (score 1):

```
class sum{
   public $num1=1;
   public function fun($num2){
        return $this->num1+$num2;
          //removed $^^
   }
}
$number = new sum();
echo $number->fun(3);
```

Comment: How were you able to post an answer?!

Comment: I don't know even I'm confused. Might be faster than you in posting. Is this an issue or else. @Rizier123